# Display Facebook videos in Ionic 2 app

Tags: facebook, video, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to display my Facebook videos in an ionic 2 app but the URL is not working. In browser, I am getting message "Unavailable
This video can't be embedded." and in emulators the display is blank.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link [Embeded Video Player](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player) it worked for me, I hope this would also help you. To setup Facebook SDK in your ionic app. please visit this link [Ionic Facebook Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/)

Comment: can u share your code. We also want to show facebook videos in ionic app.